# Disable map merges and simply treat them as strings

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file that has merge statement as below with undefined aliases. I am aware that such a yaml is invalid. However, I am dealing with a special case where, I need to be able to load the yaml successfully keeping the merge statement. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
yaml_str = """\
hello1 : world
foo:
    <<: *core_foo
"""
```

when I load using `ruamel.yaml.Yaml().load(yaml_str)` I want yaml to treat `<<` and `*` just as any other strings and not error on undefined aliases

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the innards of the parser, the only way to load `<<` without being interpreted as a
merge key is by using the base loader, that treats every scalar as a string. But that still cannot deal
with aliasses with appropriate anchors, so for that I suggest you replace the actual asterisks with a different character:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
hello1 : world
foo:
    <<: *core_foo
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='base')
data = yaml.load(yaml_str.replace(': *', ': ★'))
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
{'hello1': 'world', 'foo': {'<<': '★core_foo'}}
```

After loading you could recursively walk over the data structure and revert the
`★` back to a `*`.

If you need to dump this  back, make sure to create a new YAML instance that
doesn't have `typ="base"`. That way you can e.g. replace the merge key, and
revert to a non-YAML, alias-only document

```py
data['foo']['abc'] = data['foo'].pop('<<')


yaml2 = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
def revert(s):
    return s.replace('★', '*')

yaml2.dump(data, sys.stdout, transform=revert)
```

which gives:

```
hello1: world
foo:
  abc: *core_foo
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention the requirements on round tripping. I would also be dumping it back hence would need it to work for roundtripping as well. Also, it is okay for me to  treat aliases with appropriate anchors as string as well. Thanks for quick reply

Comment: It helps when you describe what you want to achieve, e.g. by giving examples of before and after. A good problem description is 3/4 of the way to a solution. So please edit your question to make it more complete, so that other will recognise your problem as theirs at sometime in the future without reading comments to answers.